# What is a memory-efficient algorithm for sampling from a high-dimensional multivariate normal?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, high-dimensional

Is there some sort of memory-efficient approximate solution? What if all of the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are equal to $\alpha$ and all of the diagonal elements are equal to $\sigma^2$? An implementation in R would be terrific.

For additional context, the MVN has a dimension around 70000 and has a dense covariance matrix. I've tried using the standard multivariate normal packages in R but even on a machine with a lot of memory can't realistically sample from MVNs with more than a few thousand elements. I'm running simulations to test for coverage and power of parameter estimates in settings where there's high covariance between observations, and it would be helpful if I could exactly specify the covariance matrix I want to use.

Comment: It's quite straightforward. Is this an exercise for some class?

Comment: Note that this covariance structure is that of a random-intercept model, so you can simply simulate data from a random intercept model that has the corresponding covariances and variances.

Comment: Thanks for the response Glen_b. I've tried to find a reference for simulating data from random intercept models but can't find a solution that doesn't run into the same problem. I'm adding more context to the original question.

Comment: For the situation you describe in the first paragraph, you could sample a single $X \sim N(0,\alpha)$ and a vector of _independent_ $\epsilon_j \sim N(0, \sigma^2 - \alpha)$; then $Y_j = \mu_j + X + \epsilon_j$ will give you the desired MVN.

Comment: Totally agree with other comments, but I think Mark might have a minor typo, as there is an extra symbol? Maybe omit the mu from the last eq, as in p = 100000 eps = rnorm(p, 0, sqrt(sigma - alpha) ) #within group variation x = rnorm(1, 0, sqrt (alpha) )#shared/group variation output = x + eps